# What is the Protosemitic root for asher?

Tags: semitic-languages, roots

What is the protosemitic root for asher(אשר) in:

`ehyeh asher ehyeh`

`אהיה אשר אהיה`

from Exodus 3:14

Note: I'm not sure but I'm guessing it's probably either ʔṯr, ʔšr, or ʔśr.

Comment: You can find a thorough treatment in Huehnergard (2006), '[On the Etymology of the Hebrew Relative *šƐ-*](https://www.academia.edu/234662/2006_On_the_Etymology_of_the_Hebrew_Relative_%C5%A1%C9%9B)', in Steven E. Fassberg and Avi Hurvitz (eds.), *Biblical Hebrew in Its Northwest Semitic Setting: Typological and Historial Perspectives*, pp. 103–125. You are invited to write a summary as an answer to your own question.

Comment: not all Semitic vocabulary derives from roots, especially function words and concrete nouns. Absent a pretty convincing argument (I've yet to read the paper Keelan raises), the most likely explanation would seem to be a relation to various other particles with š e.g. še "that" and 'iš "there is"

Comment: if it does derive from a root, ʔśr would be unlikely as ś usually becomes sin in Hebrew whereas אשר has a shin (the two are not distinguished in unpointed writing, but in writing with niqqud they are, and the two are pronounced differently, sin merging with samekh as /s/ and shin of course being /ʃ/)

Comment: @Tristan Isn't that not always the case (with the niqqud), although it does have a somewhat biased pattern, I think it is not safe to generalize it that way. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but didn't ś become š (shin) in Hebrew, and it became s (sin) in Arabic (ie. with the word for sun in Semitic languages)?

Comment: You are correct. Pointing is used on ש to distinguish śin /s/ from šin /ʃ/ in Hebrew, but this is not the only thing for which pointing is used. The two points mentioned by @Tristan (difference in pointing and difference in pronunciation) is really only one, since the former is based on the latter. In Arabic, *š merged with *s, and *ś eventually became /ʃ/. See the table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_languages#Consonants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the article mentioned in the above comment by Keelan, "On the Etymology of the Hebrew Relative šƐ-," the possible roots and the connection between šƐ- and ašer indicates that ašer probably derived from aṯeru (ʔṯru), meaning "place," to eventually becoming a relative pronoun in certain Semitic languages.